# AngularJS: Binding once to an attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I am trying to bind once an object key/field to the value of an attribute (`data-oldField`) so that if its value changes via user input (`angular x-editable tables`) I can grab the html element via `data-newField` and get the value of `data-oldField` so that I can rename the field/key in the object. I tried using the native `::` expression to bind once, but the value of `data-oldField` changes when a change to the field name is submitted so that the values of `date-oldField` and `data-newField` are equal afterwards which is precisely what I do not want.

I also tried using the `angular-once` library and adding the directives `once once-attr-field='field'` as per the [api](https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once), but I got the same result.

```
<tr ng-repeat='(field, value) in user.data'>
  <td>
    <span editable-text='field' e-name='name' e-form='rowform' data-newField='{{ field }}' data-oldField='{{ ::field }}' e-required>
      {{ field }}
      </span>
  </td>

...

</tr>
```

### Edit:

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O1LdltPLEGRAWVaSTkED?p=preview)**

I was unable to get the values of the `data-oldfield` and `data-newfield` attributes to show on the view, but if you observe the values of the attributes using your brower's dev tools and press the "Rename Field" button, you can see the that the value of `data-oldfield` changes even though I'm using one time binding. Maybe I'm misunderstanding how the $watchers work for this kind of binding?

Comment: could you provide a plunkr?

Comment: @user2954587 I've added one, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the angular docs it appears that using `::` will be updating the object to a new value but will not be updating to view:

```
An expression that starts with :: is considered a one-time expression. One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value (see value stabilization algorithm below).
```

I'm not quite sure I understand the question but one approach would be to 
defined a function in your controller that would be called on `ng-change` that could perform your logic.

Another would be to `$watch` the model but watching can be expensive

*UPDATE*

I'm a bit confused what exactly you're trying to accomplish but here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yAljY6qtTJuJ5eCQ3dDY?p=preview) that has an ng-change where you can reference the new value and the old value of `$scope.user` using a copy of the object. You can also use the `renameField` function however you'd like

Comment: I don't think `ng-change` and `$watch` help me here. The reason I'm trying to do one time binding is to keep track of which field/key is being renamed. I currently have no other way of accessing or recording the old field once it has changed. With both the old and new fields, I can then iterate through an array of objects to rename the field in each.